# Add response code in json

Tags: php, json

I have a php script that gives response in json for my android applicaiton.

The json :

```
{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"mahmudul hasan","name":"mahmudul hasan","2":"364","roll":"364","3":"sohel","qrcode":"sohel"}
```

But i also want to get status with the resonse like below :

```
 {
  "0": "1",
  "1": "mahmudul hasan",
  "2": "364",
  "3": "sohel",
  "id": "1",
  "name": "mahmudul hasan",
  "roll": "364",
  "qrcode": "sohel",
  **"success": true**
 }
```

My PHP coed for json response :

```
    foreach ($data as $item)
    {
        if($item!=NULL)
        {
            echo json_encode($item); 
        }
        else
        {
            echo json_encode($item);            
        }
    }
```

How should i add the response status ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something Like this

```
foreach($data as $item) {

    $item['status'] = false;

    if (isset($item) && is_array($item)) {
        $item['status'] = true;
    }

    echo json_encode($item);
}
```

Apart from this why can't you try:-

```
foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
    if (is_array($item) && count($item) > 0) {
        $data[$key]['status'] = true;
    } else {
        //unset($data[$key])
        $data[$key]['status'] = false;
    }
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: let me check. is it really actual status?

Comment: can i return empty json for no data match?

Comment: @sohel14_cse_ju yes return like this {}, []. If you past values from $data then i will tell specifically.